# Can I install Ubuntu into an Acer Aspire 5634 WLMI notebook?

Tags: installation

I have an Acer Aspire 5634 WLMI notebook running Windows Xp.

Can I install Ubuntu in this machine ?

Is there anybody who already did it ?

Comment: Please no signing and no mail addresses in questions ;) And why would it not work?!

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://www.notebookreview.com/default.asp?newsID=3533) states that your model has a 1.83 GHz processor, 1 GB of RAM, and 120 GB storage. If that is correct, you meet [the installation requirements](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) of 700 MHz processing speed, 512 MiB RAM, and 5 GB storage space. Assuming you have a functioning USB port or optical drive, you can install Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  A [web search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=linux%20distro%20Acer%20Aspire%205634WLMi) shows multiple folks have done so, and I've installed [Xubuntu](http://www.xubuntu.org) (the [xfce](http://xfce.org) desktop version of Ubuntu) and [Lubuntu](http://www.lubuntu.net) (the [LXDE](http://lxde.org) version of Ubuntu) on much much slower and older machines. here are links to reports from some folks who have done it: [A](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1385480) [B](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-laptop-and-netbook-25/acer-linux-compatibility-455846/page3.html) [C](http://fitzcarraldoblog.wordpress.com/page/2/)

Comment: And, OBTW, if an answer to your question is good, please click on the checkmark-on-circle icon at left to show it was good. You can change that later if a better answer comes up which meets your needs more directly. This also adds karma points to your rep.